# Run Mac application of C++ and Qt on another Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt

I am trying run a simple C++ with QT application on another mac. I am trying to avoid having to install Qt on the other mac. This application was created in Xcode with cmake.

Two notes: my application (for some reason) does not create an .app file. It just creates a file with the name of my project (and no extension). I can run this file by double clicking, but still, it is not an .app. Does this matter?

Another thing, I am linking my application to static libraries of Qt. From what I understand, this should allow to run the application even if Qt is not installed, right? The result of running my application on the other mac is simply a terminal window that says: Instruction unknown.

Comment: You're title says your question is about an installer for Mac, but then your question doesn't talk about an installer at all. Are you asking about creating a Windows-like installer wizard or not?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking into creating an installer to solve my problem, but what I simply want is to run the application on another mac.

Comment: Ok, are you asking about running a Qt app on Mac in general, i.e. links to tutorials and such, or do you have some problem, like a specific error.

Comment: Yes, I have created an application that uses Qt. I want to run this application in another computer that does not have Qt installed. I want to know what files I have to copy to the other computer for my application to work, knowing that I have linked my application with static libraries of Qt. Thanks.

Comment: What are the versions of Qt, OS X on your developing Mac, and the version of the target Mac?

Comment: @Sara If you have linked to Qt statically, then you don't need any Qt shared libraries, obviously. The Qt code is already embedded in your executable (and it's likely above 1 MB because of that).

Comment: Ok, I am starting to suspect that Qt is actually not statically link, because the executable is too small (thanks @satuon). Now I am fitting with cmake and qt to solve this. Thanks everybody!